# How to map a variable to multiple names in Hex-Rays decompiler

Tags: ida, hexrays

Compilers often optimize variables usage, so multiple variables in the source code can be mapped to the same register (or stack variable) in the resulting assembly.

I know that registers can be renamed within a start and end addresses in the assembly view in IDA, but what about hex-rays decompiler? Can I give a name to a variable only in a part of the decompiled function, and some other in another part?

Answer (score 2):

Well exactly not a "pure" IDA solution. I use [HexRaysCodeXplorer](https://github.com/REhints/HexRaysCodeXplorer) to do the same. `Map to another variable` will be present in the right click context menu while in pseudocode mode. This plugin is filled with features which will make your life easier and small nuances you wish were present in IDA.